# Why can’t I install the module after uploading it?

Tags: commerce, 9, installation

I uploaded the Commerce Core module (8.x-2.32) from the */admin/modules/install* tab. After uploading it, the modules list shows the module as disabled. I cannot select the checkbox shown for this module to install it.

Why cannot I select the module to install it?

Comment: Typically that means it has unmet dependencies. But the UI should tell you that (e.g. _Requires: foo_module (missing)_. Also check your environment (php/mysql version etc) matches requirements for the module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the [module's project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce)

> **Drupal 9 / Commerce 2.x**
>
> **Commerce 2.x should only be installed via Composer**. The zip files on
> this page are provided for informative purposes only.

You need to install [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) if you don't have it installed already and then run in your project's Drupal root folder

```
composer require 'drupal/commerce:^2.32'
```